# laravel 9 create sidebar in admin panel

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to make a dashboard for the administrator. I have seen several tutorials but they are all either you have to integrate a package or a template. I am trying to make an admin dashboard from scratch by myself.

Admin home.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Super Admin Dashboard</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif
                        This is Admin Dashboard. You must be super privileged to be here !
               
                        @auth
                            @if(Auth::user()->hasRole('ROLE_SUPERADMIN'))
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('superadmin') }}">Dashboard</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('categories.index') }}">Categories</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('subcategories.index') }}">SubCategories</a>
                                </li>
                            @endif
                        @endauth
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

I'm trying to make a sidebar in bootstrap 5 and laravel 9 but I can't. When I remove the @extends at the top , the page shows up in white. But I would like to remove this navbar in the dashboard and make a vertical navbar by myself
Categories
SubCategories
I would like the navbar on the left to make a dropdown design and put the categories and subcategories in this dropdown, what should I do if I can't delete the extends with the layout? can someone give me the answer to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass parameters to `@extend`

```php
@extends('layouts.app', ['navbar' => false])

@section('content')
{{-- Your content --}}
@endsection
```

And in your `layouts.app`

```php
@if(!isset($navbar) || $navbar)
<nav>
{{-- Your navbar code --}}
</nav>
@endif
```